# Spring boot admin-client actuator in AWS multi region

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot-actuator

I have created admin server in one region and multiple client servers in different regions. Have opened specified ports.
However getting java.net.UnknownHostException error.

Is there a way to open a communication between admin and client ?

Because of VPC i dont know how make host to be known

Answer (score 1):

More suggestion and not an answer. But based on https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/430, there is possible to use a load balancer for accessing and also in issue is a link how it can be done with awsvpc module, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html.